# Xcode 7.3 bridging header can't see other headers

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, bridging-header

I'm creating app in Xcode 7.3 . Using libraries with Cocoapods. In one moment Xcode started not to see headers in my bridging-header. I can suggest it could be because adding new frameworks with pods (e.g. Alamofire)

It is the second time I got this issue. Last time i've just got previous working build and did the same things and it worked. But now that build also does't work.

I can get two types of error:

this if i try to import headers

[file not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd6dX.png)

and 
segmentation fault:11

with [this](http://pastebin.com/SSAA2zYK) code, if I commend them out

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have correctly set the path of your **BridgingHeader** file in **Build Settings**.

Comment: Yes, it was. I committed a working version yesterday, and now it doesn't compile

Comment: I've also tried not to import libraries and frameworks in bridging header, but also I have my obj-c files, so I have to use this header

Comment: Try to add the framework before filename as '#import XXXKit/XXX.h'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have create header file properly and set Objective-C Bridging Header path in build setting properly.